# Getting Timeout Error When Using suspendExecution and resumeExecutionWithResult with NSScriptCommand

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asynchronous, applescript-objc

I am currently making use of the `suspendExecution` and `resumeExecutionWithResult` of NSScript command in order to execute Apple Scripts asynchronously in my application. Provided below are the set of basic steps that I have taken to achieve the same.

1) Get the script command and store it in an IVAR. Now suspend the execution of the command using `[NSScriptCommand suspendExecution]`

2) Execute any transaction calls which will return the results asynchronously.

3) In the `completionHandler` of the Async call resume the execution with the fetched results i.e

```
[NSScriptCommand resumeExecutionWithResult:result]
```

The steps mentioned above work perfectly fine when I execute scripts from the Script Editor. but using an `NSAppleScript` object (when executing the scripts from say a scripts menu) to execute the same results in the following error

```
"AppleEvent timed out. Error Number: -1712"
```

The timeout error occurs almost instantaneously. Any pointers as to how this issue can be fixed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `NSUserAppleScriptTask`(available with the 10.8 SDK) instead of `NSAppleScript` to execute the Apple Script resolves this issue.